# How to do parallel flatMap in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

I need to do parallel flat map.
Let's say I have this code:

```
val coll: List<Set<Int>> = ...
coll.flatMap{set -> setOf(set, set + 1)}
```

I need something like this:

```
coll.pFlatMap{set -> setOf(set, set + 1)} // parallel execution
```

Comment: What is your question exactly, you want us to implement a parallel flat map for you?

Comment: @m0skit0 How to do parallel flatMap in Kotlin ? That's my question.

Comment: Kotlin doesn't have any parallel flat map in the SDK, you have to implement it by yourself. What have you tried?

Comment: You can also use Java 8 Streams. `coll.parallelStream().flatMap { ... }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kotlin doesn’t provide any threading out of the box.
But you can use kotlinx.coroutines to do something like this:

```
val coll: List<Set<Int>> = ...
val result = coll
 .map {set -> 
    // Run each task in own coroutine,
    // you can limit concurrency using custom coroutine dispatcher
    async { doSomethingWithSet(set) } 
 }
 .flatMap { deferred -> 
    // Await results and use flatMap
    deferred.await() // You can handle errors here
 }
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't leverage coroutines in any way, it just adds another useless layer on top of `coll.map { set -> commonPool().submit(Callable { doSomethingWithSet(set) }) }.flatMap { task -> task.join() }`

Comment: It's just an abstraction but not completely useless, you can use it in multiplatform code. Also, you can use this code without thread blocking if your doSomethingWithSet is not blocking and also suspend function and in general this function can be called only from suspend context, so also you don't want to block coroutine with Java's `join()`

Comment: Exactly, so unless you're on a multiplatform project or you already use coroutines, there's no point in adding that dependency to your project just for this.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do it without coroutines:

```
fun <T, R> Collection<T>.pFlatMap(transform: (T) -> Collection<R>): List<R> =
    parallelStream().flatMap { transform(it).stream() }.toList()
```

This solution requires Kotlin on JDK 8 or higher.

You can also make it more general (analogous to Kotlin's `flatMap`):

```
fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.pFlatMap(transform: (T) -> Iterable<R>): List<R> =
    toList()
        .parallelStream()
        .flatMap { transform(it).toList().stream() }
        .toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Coroutine scope first (runBlocking), and apply deferred execution to your function (async):

```
val coll: List<Set<Int>> = listOf()
val x = runBlocking {
    coll.map{ set ->
        async {
            setOf(set, set + 1)
        }
    }.awaitAll().flatten()
}

x ....
```